# How to change date format in solr yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ into " yyyy-mm-dd"?

Tags: apache, solr, date-format

I want to change  default date format in solr "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ" into "yyyy-mm-dd".
To change date format what is the file should change  inside solr folder?
Where and what is the configuration file which can configure date foramt?

Answer (score 8):

The date format used is a restricted form of the canonical representation of dateTime in the [XML Schema specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime). You can not change the solr default date format.

And `schema.xml` is the file to configure the date field.

Example:

```
<field name="Date" datetimeformat="YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:sss'Z'" 
indexed="true" multivalued="false" stored='true' type="date"> </field>
```

Comment: Your answer helps me lot and we can not change default date format to correctly index date Mysql database should have "DateTime"/Timestamp data type for date column.

Comment: You probably don't want capital YYYY because that is the week-year, you want lowercase yyyy

Answer (score 0):

To do this while using javascript I used the `split` method.

```
var newdate = olddate.split("T")[0];
output += newdate;
return output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options

1. you can perhaps make your XSLT transform the date if importing from XML
2. use DataImportHandler and DateTransformer: 
   http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#DateFormatTransformer